# Switch Collectionviews Header/Footer via kind

Tags: ios, swift, header, switch-statement, collectionview

I have a header and a footer in my CollectionView and I want both of them to be displayed. At the current state, I get 2x the Header, because the "kind" of the Section does not automatically change and it enters the case "*UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader*" twice.

I could switch the indexPath instead of the kind but I want to know the other approach aswell.

```
func setupCollectionView() {
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView?.register(ProfileHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: ProfileHeader.reuseIdentifier)
    collectionView?.register(ProfileFooter.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: ProfileFooter.reuseIdentifier)
}

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: ProfileHeader.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ProfileHeader
        header.user = self.user
        return header

    case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
        let footer = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: ProfileFooter.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ProfileFooter
        return footer

    default:
        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
```

Comment: Your current method is perfectly fine...

Comment: I get the headerview twice.. (As I wrote in the question)

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that I forgot to define the reference size of the footer. Without it, the kind is not perceived by the application.